# How to write a SQL function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to do a `function` get the price of the item automatically in database by the input of user at the `textbox("@Html.TextBox("ItemID")")` with a `handle` method.

```
//SalesSub.cs
public class SalesSub
{
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}

//Create.cshtml
<script type="text/javascript">
function handle(e) {
     //Detect when the user press 'Enter' Or 'Tab' Key
     var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
     if (keyCode === 13 || keyCode == 9) {
         var itemID = $('#ItemID').val()
         //Get the item ID in the textbox value, 
         //so how to search the price of the 
         //item in database? Using SQL or Others?
         $('#UnitPrice').val() = //Result After Search
     }
     return false;
 }

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
</script>
<label>Item ID :</label>
 **@Html.TextBox("ItemID", string.Empty, new { onkeydown = "handle(event)" })**
<label>Qty :</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Qty")
<label>Sales Price :</label>
    @Html.TextBox("UnitPrice")
}
```

Comment: I guess your post may have received the downvotes because it is unclear what the problem is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: yes,first i wan to allow the user type the item ID in the "ItemID" textBox, while in the same time, after the user finished enter the Item ID and press either 'Enter' or 'Tab' key on keyboard, then the function handle() can get the price of the item automatically. So, my problem is how can I get the price of the item? Is it using SQL? So how I write the SQL in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript on the clientside, it is not possible to get the data from the SQL server. The solution here is a webservice. Usually you implement it with either of two technologies "SOAP" or "REST" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer.
As far as I can see, you are using ASP.NET MVC4. Then you are lucky to use Web-API to build easily REST-Services: http://www.asp.net/web-api

If you want to go open source: maybe looking at http://www.openstack.org/ might be of some interest or http://nancyfx.org/.

Anyways, you have to do the job (retrieving the data) on the server side, serialize it to JSON  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON and update your form. The technique on the client side used, to get the data is called ajax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)